# Why didn't the PPDC consider rebuilding Crimson Typhoon?

Tags: pacific-rim

So I watched *Pacific Rim* again last week, and one scene stuck in my head since then, the destruction of Crimson Typhoon in the battle of Hong Kong Bay.

Compared to the Jaegers that were destroyed in the first movie, Crimson Typhoon is the least damaged Jaeger out of the 4 remaining Jaegers prior to their respective destruction scenes. I mean, the head was just ripped off and nothing else, albeit some fall damage after it fell into the Bay, but that is the extent of the damage overall, right? I mean, when compared to Cherno Alpha, Typhoon got off easy.

So then that raises the question, if the PPDC reinstated the Jaeger program after the battle of the Breach, why wasn't the reconstruction of Crimson Typhoon considered in the slightest?

Comment: I wonder if there was any group of more than 2 people piloting Jaegers, beside the Crimson Typhoon brothers (and possibly the 3 children in Pacific Rim 2).

Comment: AFAIK Crimson Typhoon's pilot system was only possible due to the fact that the pilots were triplets. Other than that it would have been impossible to pilot a three man rig. As for the kids, I would argue that their link is possible due to the advancements in Drift technology during the first and second films. Other than that, I don't think there are any other 3 pilot Jaegers out there.

Comment: Though I have no official support for my claim, that might be another reason they didn't salvage it.

Comment: True. But then again. I doubt the Wei Tang Triplets were the only capable of piloting Typhoon. I am sure that there are other pairs of triplets out there whp can pilot the mech.

Comment: Plus, like I said, the advancements in Drift technology should allow the PPDC to ignore this issue entirely, as seen in Uprising

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The film's [official novelisation](http://pacificrim.wikia.com/wiki/Pacific_Rim:_The_Official_Movie_Novelization) indicates that the damage to Crimson Typhoon was significant, presumably putting it well beyond economic repair. The removal of the headpiece was merely the coup de grâce on a robot that was already critically wounded.

- **Damage to the armour on the torso**

  > ... *the kaiju’s tail snapped forward with deadly timing to cut holes in Crimson Typhoon’s armor at vital junctures.*
- **Damage to the power system for the main plasma weapon**

  > *The Weis were trying to get their I-22 Plasmacaster warmed up, but
  >   already Otachi had damaged the channels that fed the plasma
  >   reservoirs.*
- **Critical damage to the jaeger's left arm, critical damage to primary weapon and significant damage to the secondary weapon**

  > *One of the twinned gauntlets on the left was gone. From the other hung the bent and useless saw assembly, all of the saw’s teeth broken off.*
- **Water entering the main chassis and causing electrical shorts**

  > Crimson Typhoon’s skull frame was partially torn open and seawater was
  >   beginning to short out its motor arrays.
- **Removal of the con-pod, containing the control interface and power control systems**

  > With a deafening grind of tearing metal, accompanied by the flare of
  >   ruptured energy conduits, Otachi tore Crimson Typhoon’s head off and
  >   crushed it.

Comment: Woah. These are some very valid points made here, which is extremely commendable. But I would still argue that the damage caused to the Jaeger would be cheaper to finance rather than building entirely new Jaegers from scratch all over again. Just my opinion here. Looking at the points made, I would like to think that the damage could have been a LOT worse, again when compared to the destroyed wreck of Cherno Alpha. I would think that some points here are superficial. But then again. Just my opinion. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @GipsyD - Sometimes a vehicle is [broken beyond the cost of replacing it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-off). That doesn't mean it couldn't be theoretically fixed, just that it's cheaper to make a new one.

Comment: You make a compelling case. I like that. It would make sense to replace Crimson Typhoon with a new Jaeger, like Saber Athena

Comment: But still. I think it would still be viable for the PPDC to use Typhoon as a training/patrol Jaeger like November Ajax, rather than bringing the Jaeger back up to combat readiness. More to an operational state.

Comment: @GipsyD - Plus the tech that you use in a project that was started 20+ years ago is going to be hideously outdated. Note that if we were going to the moon again, we could replace the entire (70lb) onboard computer on the Apollo missions with a single chip the size of a grain of salt.

Comment: Alright. Alright. Point made. I think it's just the nostalgia talking here. Like I said, a very compelling case. Thanks again for your input!

Answer (score -3):

You could just salvage a Jaeger's head for example, Tacit Ronin, and remove the right arms, create a copy for the left, repair the left, then try to upgrade the conpod to the PPDC standards and you're ready for battle. That way there'd be three Jaegers that fight in the breach: Gipsy vs Scunner, Striker vs Slattern and Typhoon vs Raiju.